# Why this program need more than 45 input to occur buffer overflow(segmentaion fault)?

Tags: c, overflow

Why this program needs more than 45 input to occur buffer overflow(segmentaion fault)?

```
  #include <stdio.h> 
  #include <string.h> 

  int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
  { 
      char whatever[20];
      strcpy(whatever, argv[1]);
      return 0;
  }
```

I mean it should be more than 24 char input.by the way there is no grsecurity enabled in my system.and i'm using ubuntu 7.04 32bit on virtual box.

Comment: Going out of bounds leads to *undefined behavior* which means really anything can happen, including seemingly working fine.

Comment: what do you mean by "it should be more than 24"?

Comment: You are probably on 64-bit; try to compile it for 32 bit, then your expectations should be better met. (`gcc -O2 foo.c -o foo -m32`)

Comment: Because buffer overflows are not definitively diagnosed.  Suppose you're speeding along the highway, but the speed limit is just 55 mph.  How many mph more than 55, and for how many minutes, will you have to drive before a cop pulls you over and gives you a speeding ticket?  We obviously can't say exactly.  (In fact sometimes you can get away with it for an arbitrarily long time.)  Same thing here.

Comment: Can you please run ```objdump -d main``` (or whatever your executable is called) and post this here? I'll try to guide you through why this happens.

Comment: @MayurK 24 character needs to overflow the stack in mathematical manner.because in 32 bit system(4 byte system) we have can't have 21(why 21? because the buffer is 20 plus a prolog stuff , refer to Shellcoder's handbook book) byte stack allocated memory.in this scenario we should have 24 byte stack.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude but i saw in different systems different input will overflow the stack. look at this -> https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/buffer-overflow-attack-with-example/  .in this example i need more than 34 character input i think.not 9 input.

Comment: @Ctx i'm using ubuntu 7.04 32bit The Art Of Exploitation book sources in virtualbox environment.

Comment: @DanyZatuchna here is objdump text file, https://gofile.io/?c=iGbfeL .

Comment: @aidinjalalvandi That's one of the points of [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)... *Anything* can happen! Sometimes it seems to work, sometimes it crashes your system, sometimes you need X amount for buffer overflow, sometimes Y amount, and sometimes it summons [nasal demons](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html) to format your drives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, what's interesting here is the disassembly of `main`:

```
push   %ebp
mov    %esp,%ebp
sub    $0x38,%esp
and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
mov    $0x0,%eax
sub    %eax,%esp
mov    0xc(%ebp),%eax
add    $0x4,%eax
mov    (%eax),%eax
mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
lea    0xffffffd8(%ebp),%eax
mov    %eax,(%esp)
call   80482a0 <strcpy@plt>
mov    $0x0,%eax
leave  
ret
```

Before entering `main`, the stack pointer `esp` points to the return address pushed by `call`. Let's call that `&ret`.

The first opcode in the function pushes the base pointer of the previous frame, and then sets the current base pointer to the stack pointer. So `ebp = &ret - 4`.

When setting up the call to `strcpy`, the value right at `esp` is the first parameter. Here:

```
mov    %eax,(%esp)
call   80482a0 <strcpy@plt>
```

So the value in `eax` is the first parameter. If we look at the previous instruction, we can see what that value is:

```
lea    0xffffffd8(%ebp),%eax
```

Ok, this notation basically means: `eax = ebp + 0xffffffd8`, which is equivalent to `eax = ebp - 40` (see [Two's Complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)). Basically, you flip all the bits (and get 0x27=39), stick a minus sign (-39), and subtract 1 (-40).

And in relation to the frame's return address: `eax = &ret - 44`

So it would take at least 45 bytes to overrun the return address.

But you say 47. This is interesting, and it might have to do with the specific input you supplied.

You see, x86 is a [little-endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Little-endian) little endian machine, which means that in memory, integers are stored LSB-first. So, when overwriting the stored return address, you first overwrite it's LSB.

If your input happens to be in the vicinity of the LSB, you might cause a faulty termination, but not a segmentation fault, as you will cause a branch to a legitimate address.

If you'll share your input, it might help shed some light on those two missing bytes :)

Comment: Thanks a lot mr. Dany, i was wrong.it need 44 for Illegal instruction and 45 for segmentaton fault.i think i have to work with assembly a lot to master the exploitation.

Comment: The point i figured it out (true or wrong) is that it all depends on compiler by the equal hardwares.right? because the compiler is responsible for creating assembly codes. i think that's why i saw different inputs in different places.

Comment: Another question here is why there is this " lea  0xffffffd8(%ebp),%eax " ?? this line will add the stack 40 byte right?? but why??

Comment: About the ```lea```,  local variables are addressed on the stack, using either ```ebp``` or ```esp```, depending on the compiler.

Comment: Also, I forgot that we're talking about ```strcpy``` here, which means that when you supply a 40 byte input, ```strcpy``` will write a string terminator (0) at the 41 position. This is why when you supplies 44bytes, you set the LSB of the saved return address to 0, which probably puts it in the middle of an instruction, hence the SIGILL. For 45bytes, you made the saved return address point way outside the executable, which caused a SIGSEGV. (Just shows you how details are important when dealing with exploitation)

Comment: I still didn't catch this part "lea 0xffffffd8(%ebp),%eax ". why do we need 40 byte??? i have created a 20 byte array. there is no other local variables here.